# CSS and js files not loaded in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I inserted links to my assets directly in `application.html.erb`. I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H7H0tgqwoSk). Here is my `routes.db`:

```
get 'sale/show'
  devise_for :sales
  get 'carousels/show'
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  get 'pages/show'
  get 'home/show'
  get 'sections/show'
  get 'man', to: 'sections#show'
  get 'sale/show'
  get 'yemi', to: 'sale#show'
  get 'application/hhome'

  resources :pages, :sections, only: [:show]
```

In the index page, the assets are loaded but in other pages, they are not loaded. The pages I route as:

```
get 'something', to: 'a link'
```

loads the assets, but those that are just direct:

```
get 'something'
```

do not load the assets.

Since I added css and jss directly, those css files are in my public folder because I am using am html template, the style sheet and js files are disorganised, so I can't move them to the assets in views.

How can I make all pages find the assets?

Comment: What is jss? ...

Answer (score 1):

1. First, Make sure you have these 2 lines in your `application.html.erb`

   ```
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
   ```
2. You can safely add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/your_css_file.css">` above these 2 lines.(But not recommended this way)
3. Make sure you have `require_tree .` line in your `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` file:

   ```
   *= require_tree .
   *= require_self
   */
   ```
4. And also in `application.js` make sure you have `//= require_tree .` line. If not then add them.